# Why is Krishna often addressed by his father's name - Vasudev?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

Why is Krishna often addressed by his father's name - Vasudev ? Is Vasudev also some kind of post , title or anything like that ?

Answer (score 1):

According to Sanjaya -

> From that, as far as I can make out, Keshava cannot be measured. **Because he clothes all beings, because he is the womb of all the gods, he is known as Vasudeva.”**

731 (68), Yana-Sandhi Parva, Mahabharata.

2. According to lord Krishna himself -

> "Assuming the form of Surya, I envelop the world and the universe with
> my rays. **Since I am the dwelling of all creatures, I am Vasudeva.** O
> descendant of the Bharata lineage! I am the destination of all
> creatures and subjects.”

Chapter 1656 ( 328), Moksha-Dharma Parva, Mahabharata

Answer (score 0):

Though the name Vāsudeva also means Antaratma. Lord Krishna is called Vāsudeva mostly due to his father's name Vasudeva.

ŚB 10.51.39-40.:

> Nonetheless, O friend, I will tell you about My current birth, name and activities. Kindly hear. Some time ago, Lord Brahmā requested Me to protect religious principles and destroy the demons who were burdening the earth. Thus I descended in the Yadu dynasty, in the home of Ānakadundubhi. **Indeed, because I am the son of Vasudeva, people call Me Vāsudeva.**

Note.: Lord Krishna's father is called Vasudeva (वसुदेव), whereas Lord Krishna is called Vāsudeva/Vaasudeva (वासुदेव).

Even Lord Rama and Lord Parshurama are called by their father's name.

Valmiki Ramayana.:

> On receiving the deference paid by the sage Vashishta, **that inexorable Rama of Jamadagni (jāmadagnyo) started to talk to Rama of Dasharatha (dāśharathim).** [1-74-24].

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..