# Is this a valid Sanskrit mantra for Krishna?

Tags: krishna, sanskrit

[Devraha Baba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devraha_Baba) used to give [this Krishna mantra](https://www.facebook.com/devraha/posts/3908500345860643/) to people.

ॐ कृष्णाय वासुदेवाय हरये परमात्मने॥ प्रणत: क्लेशनाशाय गोविंदाय नमो नम:॥

Is it a valid Sanskrit mantra ?

What is its meaning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> कृष्णाय To Lord Krishna 
> वासुदेवाय For son of Vasudeva 
> हरये (हरे+ ए ) For Lord Hari
> परमात्मने The supreme Lord
> प्रणत bowed dow(surrender)
> क्लेश affliction (suffering due to mental/physical distress)
> नाशाय destroy
> गोविन्दाय To Lord Govinda
> नमो नम: repeated obeisances
>
> Again and again we offer our obeisances unto Lord Kṛṣṇa, Hari, the son of Vasudeva. That Supreme Soul, Govinda, vanquishes the suffering of all who surrender to Him.
>
> Srimad Bhagavata puranam [10.73.16](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/73/16/)

Comment: Does "Vaasudev" mean , [son of Vasudev ?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55399/why-is-krishna-often-addressed-by-his-fathers-name-vasudev) Vaasudev is often used to address Krishna. The name of Krishna's father is also Vasudev ? 
Is Vasudev used for Krishna for Krishna's father ? Or Is Vaasudev used for both of them ? 
Are both of them different names ?

Comment: @river , The elongation or vridhhi of the first vowel(va to vaa) , along with certain suffix rules , signifies belonging to , or derived from *the parent word in the hierarchy* (by Sanskrit linguistics, to my knowledge) Similar deravations can be found ..sage vyasa is known as vaasishta, being the great grand son of vasishta.Lord Rama is known as Kaakustha(because of His ancestor Kakushtha) . Draupadi derives her name from Drupada  and Paarvati  is derived from  Parvata..Lord Krishna is also known as Vaarshneya, as he belongs to Vrishni race. Yaadhava (being descendant of Yadu) etc.

Comment: **So Vasudev is father , whose son Vaasudev is Lord Krishna**